# Dynamic pages in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, redirect

I'm building a small mvc4 site, but I've run in to a little problem :/

The site will have an admin area, and in this area the administrator of the site, should be able to dynamicly create new pages.
Let's say the admin creates a new page called "World" under another page called "hello".
Now when a user navigates to the.domain.com/hello/World this newly created page should be shown.
It's basicly the functionality of a very simple CMS system.

So, what I need is a way to redirect all calls not already covered by a controller and action, to one specific action on one specific controller.

I've done this before in webforms using urlrewriting.
I just checked if the aspx page existed on disk, and if it didn't I redirected to a page called something like pagehandler.aspx?pageid={some_page_id}, but I guess there is a way to do it with routing in mvc4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass strings to `View()`, so you should be able to catch this with a route like this:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DynamicPageView",
    url: "Page/{pageName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "DisplayPage", pageName = "Index" }
    );
```

This would hit a method like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DisplayPage(string pageName)
{
    return View(viewName: pageName);
}
```

I've done something similar myself to host mockups; a controller method like this can handle an arbitrary number of pages and can easily be extended to handle subfolders, so it's great for quickly throwing together dummy pages that can be navigated like a real site.

Having said all that, it's worth saying that where possible, I'd prefer to keep end users (even the admins) away from the internals that this would expose. Instead, you should probably come up with a model that represents what will be on the page, store that, and use a template to display it by ID or title.

Comment: Just testet it, and it Works fine. Thanks :)